# Put single quotes in string javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string

Currenly i use javascript to bind a table dynamically..

I need single quotes to delimit a string..

Code :-

```
var str ="";
str += "<td><a onclick='showFlightsByName("+val.Name+")' href='javascript:;'><span>" + val.Name + "</span></a></td>";
```

Current Ouput :-

```
<a onclick="showFlightsByName(AirTran Airways)" href="javascript:;"><span>Airways Airways</span></a>
```

Desire Output :-

```
<a onclick="showFlightsByName('AirTran Airways')" href="javascript:;"><span>Airways Airways</span></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"<td><a onclick='showFlightsByName("+val.Name+")' href='javascript:;'><span>" + val.Name + "</span></a></td>"
```

should be

```
"<td><a onclick=\"showFlightsByName('"+val.Name+"')\" href=\"javascript:;\"><span>" + val.Name + "</span></a></td>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var str ="";
str += "<td><a onclick=\"showFlightsByName('"+val.Name+"')\" href=\"javascript:;\"><span>" + val.Name + "</span></a></td>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Often when working with HTML it's easier to use `'` instead of `"` for Strings, like this:

```
var str = '<td><a onclick="showFlightsByName("' + val.Name + '")" href="javascript:;"><span>' + val.Name + '</span></a></td>';
```

However, have you considered using JS to build the DOM object?

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "javascript:;";
a.onclick = "showFlightsByName(" + val.Name + ")";
a.appendChild(document.createElement("span").innerHTML(val.name));
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.appendChild(a);
```

That might not be 100%. It's been a while since I've coded in plain JS. JQuery makes it too easy.

edit: on that note...

```
var $a = $('<a>').append($('<span>').text(val.Name)).click(function() {
    showFlightsByName(val.Name); 
});
$('<td>').append($a).appendTo("WHEREVER");
```